# how to schedule a container to run whenever new data gets inserted into database?

Tags: docker, containers, schedule

how to schedule a container to run whenever new data gets inserted into database? Like i want my container to run whenever new write request came into my PostgreSQL database.

In cron i can schedule container to run on specific time but not on data come basis.

Comment: how will you know the new data is there ? is this an expected data ?

Comment: yes some data will be write in DB on daily basis.

Comment: then you may check with `select exists(select WHATEVER from WHATEVER where .....)`

Comment: In that case how i can schedule the container to run on database write change?

Comment: with cronjobs if that statement is TRUE then run else nothing

Comment: You can create a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html) on inserts in PostgreSQL to execute a callback function when the event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use producer and consumer mechanism, often used with the RabbitMQ service.
within your application there should be an event (example: Propel postInsert() or postUpdate() methods) and when that event happens, put an item to the queue.
then, make the consumer go through the items and run a container run command.